# Element is not exported warning for JavaScript in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I don't understand why I am receiving the `element is not exported` in WebStorm IDE for the following JavaScript at the `this.errors` line.

```
function FooBar(userId, email) {
  if (!util.isString(userId) || !userId.length) {
    throw Error('FooBar(): requires a non-empty userId:String');
  }

  if (this instanceof FooBar) {
    this.id = generateId();
    this.userId = userId;
    this.email = email;
    this.curStep = WORKER_STEPS[0];
    this.completed = false;
    this.failed = false;
    this.createDate = new Date();
    this.errors = {};
    for (let step of WORKER_STEPS) {
      this.errors[step] = 0;
    }
  } else {
    return new FooBar(userId, email);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: just one question, is it NodeJS v.6.x.x?

Comment: Lucky that it supports ES6! (; https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/

Answer (score 1):

I know I can get many downvotes, cuz it's out of scope of question.

But it's time to switch to ES6.
So I'll give You better solution (:

1) Turn on EcmaScript 6 support:

[image: WS-ES6]

2) Switch to `class` es to avoid enormous old-school class definition using `function`

Add this to top of js files, it will make nodejs interpreter to alert about memory leeks or unnecessary variable definition and etc nice features.

```
/* jshint strict: true */

'use strict';
```

And here is Your `FooBar`:

```
const
  _ = require('lodash');

class Entity {
  hasError() {
    return !_.isEmpty(this.errors);
  }

  addError(step, error) {
    this.errors[step] = error;
  }

  getErrors() {
    return this.errors;
  }
} 

class FooBar extends Entity {

  constructor(userId, email, steps = []) {
    if (_.isEmpty(userId) || !_.isString(userId))
      throw Error('FooBar(): requires a non-empty userId:String');

    this.id = generateId();
    this.userId = userId;
    this.email = email;
    this.curStep = _.first(steps);
    this.completed = false;
    this.failed = false;
    this.createDate = new Date();
    this.errors = {};
  }
}
```

usage:

```
let 
  fooBar = new FooBar(
             '1f049de1-b592-4f17-9a7d-3f2097477b23',
             'somebody@gmail.com', 
             WORKER_STEPS);

  fooBar.addError(0, "Something happen"); // or fooBarInstance.addError("Somewhere", "Something happen");

if(fooBar.hasError()) {
  console.error(fooBarInstance.getErrors());
}
```

Comment: I updated the code, would you mind taking another look. I don't understand how errors is different from any of the other properties.